# How to import custom css files using Chakra UI for React?

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

This is a very specific question, but I am using the Chakra UI component library for React and I want to import my own custom `css` files, although it doesn't allow me to do this.

I don't know if this is a bug or if it is intended, but is there any way I can go around it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you import `css` files in right place. Try to import your `css` files into `App.js` or if be more specific into the file where you init `ChakraProvider`. This approach works fine for my project:

```
import { ChakraProvider } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import './yourCssFile.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend or override a token in the default theme by importing the **extendTheme** function. You can override properties as well as add new ones.
But if you want to add an external CSS file, I've found out from reading the docs that in order to import other file types (.css, .woff or .svg) in your theme file, you'll need to move those imports out of the theme file.

Comment: The import statement is not in the theme file, and it still does not work

Comment: You can try reading https://chakra-ui.com/docs/theming/customize-theme, it may help.

Comment: Maybe this should be a different question, but what configuration do I modify to change the background color or the webpage?

Comment: for css, background-color: red;
in chakraUI, backgroundColor: 'red'